# Ruby mail gem - search inbox from specific email addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, imap, mail-gem

Does anybody know how to get mail from an array of email addresses using the 'mail' gem in Ruby? I've seen the thread for getting unread messages like so:

```
new_messages = Mail.find(keys: ['NOT','SEEN'])
```

But I cannot find how to get messages from a certain address. I've tried:

```
new_messages = Mail.find(keys: ['FROM','example@hello.com'])
```

but it doesn't work.

I know section [6.4.4 of the IMAP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2060#section-6.4.4) indicates the different search flags you can use to search for messages, but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither

```
Mail.find( keys: ['FROM', from_address] )
```

nor

```
Mail.find( keys: "FROM #{from_address}" )
```

worked. What worked, however, is quoting the email address:

```
Mail.find( keys: "FROM \"#{from_address}\”" )
```

Luckily, it was just the missing quotes, as the array variant works as well when quoting the email address:

```
Mail.find( keys: ['FROM', "\"#{from_address}\”"] )
```

Comment: how can we get emails based on from date and to date?

Answer (score 0):

Try this for single email address

```
Mail.all.select { |mail| mail.from.addresses.include?('example@hello.com') }
```

And for multiple try this

```
addresses = ['example@hello.com', 'test@hello.com']
Mail.all.select { |mail| (addresses - mail.from.addresses).empty? }
```

Also if you want to find just first mail try this

```
Mail.all.find { |mail| mail.from.addresses.include?('example@hello.com') }
```

Comment: Thanks Amit - would this still be loading in all the messages first and then filtering them out? I'm trying to only search the actual inbox for the specified emails to keep things fast.